# How do I create a NumPy array from results of a pyodbc query?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, pyodbc

I would like to create an array or list from values pulled from a SQL query.  From research I believe the data I pull from SQL is a tuple.

How do format the data into a list I can use in python?

In my current code I try to use the numpy command np.asarray.  I'm not sure if numpy arrays allow datetime.

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('login')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT PTIME, PVALUE FROM HISTORY_TABLE WHERE POINT = 'Value' AND PTIME> '2017-04-12' AND PTIME<'2017-04-13' AND HISTTYPE='AVG' AND PERIOD=7200")

sample = cursor.fetchall()
rockin = np.asarray(sample)
print rockin

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

My result looks like this:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 12, 0, 0) 232.83]
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 12, 2, 0) 131.49]
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 12, 4, 0) 36.67]
 ..., 
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 12, 18, 0) 82.08]
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 12, 20, 0) 368.83]
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 12, 22, 0) 435.79]]
```

Comment: Why not use Pandas?

Comment: Thanks Henry, you were right, "Why not Pandas?"  So much easier.  So, So, much easier.  Thank you.

Comment: @getaglow btw I think there's panda examples in the beta docs... (By me?? Can't remember now..)

Comment: @getaglow  back home and on computer (late!).. no, i started the scipy docs not the panda docs .. knew i did something snake-ish! ;)   But yeah, plenty on pandas in the docs if you want to explore..

Comment: @getaglow hi, do you know what those arrows are for beside the answers? I see from you profile you don't vote very much. Upvotes award your helping assistants time and effort (just click the top arrow) .. Reserve your accepts (the hover+click - which you seem to only have done once) for working answers, but you can upvote up to 30 (or is 40?) times in a day, and you should upvote the people who help you along the way to recognise their efforts. (how do you think you got your rep?.. people upvoted your questions! Now you have the privilege to vote up others! Use it.. thanks)..

Comment: @getaglow note that you can only **accept 1 answer per question** but you can **upvote** as many answers as you like..

Answer (score 2):

> From research I believe the data I pull from SQL is a tuple.

Not exactly. pyodbc's `fetchall()` method does not return a list of tuples, it returns a list of `pyodbc.Row` objects:

```python
>>> rows = crsr.execute("SELECT 1 AS foo UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS foo").fetchall()
>>> rows
[(1, ), (2, )]
>>> type(rows[0])
<type 'pyodbc.Row'>
```

It could be that `np.asarray` does not know how to handle `pyodbc.Row` objects. If you want to convert each row to an actual tuple you can use

```python
>>> rows_as_tuples = [tuple(x) for x in rows]
>>> rows_as_tuples
[(1,), (2,)]
>>> type(rows_as_tuples[0])
<type 'tuple'>
```